# Why does this Recursive Java Program not correctly reverse lines from a text file

Tags: java, recursion

As a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480212/read-in-n-lines-of-an-input-stream-and-print-in-reverse-order-without-using-array)

Where the idea was to print lines from a file in reverse without using an explicit data structure I have an implementation question. Recursion was suggested and here's what I have:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReverseLines {
   public ReverseLines() {
   }

   public void reverse(File fileToReverse, int n) {
      try {
         FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileToReverse);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
         String line = br.readLine();
         if (n > 0) {
            reverse(fileToReverse, n - 1);
         }
         System.out.println(line);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      ReverseLines testReverse = new ReverseLines();
      File test = new File("money.txt");
      testReverse.reverse(test, 3);
   }
}
```

This code prints the first line of money.txt 3 times instead of the first three lines in reverse. Frankly (and naively) I don't see how the recursion is supposed to work if just readLine(); is used.

Help is appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always reading the first line of the file. Change it like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReverseLines {
   public ReverseLines() {
   }

   public void reverse(BufferedReader br, int n) {
      try {            
         String line = br.readLine();
         if (n > 0) {
            reverse(br, n - 1);
            System.out.println(line);
         }             
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      ReverseLines testReverse = new ReverseLines();
      File test = new File("money.txt");

      FileReader fr = new FileReader(test );
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 

      testReverse.reverse(br, 3);
   }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to try,catch `FileNotFoundException` when creating FileReader, or declare main as throwing this exception

Answer (score 4):

you should use the same instance of BufferedReader rather then creating a new one in every run of the recursion.

also note that the `System.out.println()` should be inside the if condition (otherwise you print n+1 first lines)

should look something like that:

```
public class ReverseLines { 
    public void reverse(BufferedReader br, int n) {
        try {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (n > 0) {
                reverse(br, n - 1);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ReverseLines testReverse = new ReverseLines();
        File test = new File("money.txt");
        testReverse.reverse(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test)), 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: @alphazero: it is in if condition because otherwise n+1 lines will be printed, and not n as requested by the OP.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: if the print is outside of if, a line will be printed when n=0,1,2,3: total 4 lines, and I assume you want only 3 lines. to prevent it print only when n>0.

Comment: Thanks...I understand that it works...its just an odd recursion since there is no explicit base case. It just goes backwards until it is no more defined...but we know how many lines there are so we only pass valid parameters?...I guess the "base case" would be more like if(n>no_Of_Lines_in_the_file) {do something} ?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: the base case should be `if(line != null) { ... }`, since `BufferedReader` returns null when the file is exhausted, so you should keep deepening in the recursion while there is more input. I'll edit my answer to follow what we have just discussed.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear...i still want N lines. I am just troubled by the fact that if(n>0) {stuff}  does not have a clear base case. I guess the simple fix is to say if(n>1){recursive Call} system.out.println(line);

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: I reverted my answer back to the initial then. you could do that by either `if(n>1) { recursive call} print` or `if(n>0) { recursive call; print }`

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing the buffered reader every time that you call the function, which makes it seek to the beginning of the file each time before you print anything out.
Try it this way:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReverseLines 
{
   private static BufferedReader br;
   public ReverseLines() 
   {

   }

   public void reverse(File fileToReverse, int n) {
      try {
         String line = br.readLine();
         if (n > 0) {
            reverse(fileToReverse, n - 1);
         }
         System.out.println(line);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] argv) {
      ReverseLines testReverse = new ReverseLines();
      File test = new File("money.txt");
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileToReverse);
      br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      testReverse.reverse(test, 3);
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't work because you haven't defined br in the method. Right idea though!

Comment: Oops. You're right. I'll edit it.
Thought I had already moved that. Thanks!